# Grouping rows in R to calculate frequency

Tags: r

I have a data frame called df with a column called Car Type.

```
User   CarType
1      AUDI
2      BMW
3      AUDI
4      BMW
5      <NA>
6      CHEVROLET
7      <NA>
```

I am using aggregate to find frequency of each CarType.

```
freq<-aggregate(df$CarType,by=list(df$CarType),function(c) length(c))

> freq
    Group.1 x
1      Audi 2
2       BMW 2
3 CHEVROLET 1
```

How do I get frequency of NA in the entire column in the same dataframe as frequency? Required output:

```
  > freq
            Group.1 x
        1      Audi 2
        2       BMW 2
        3 CHEVROLET 1
        4        NA 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df2<-data.frame("NA",sum(is.na(df$CarType)))
colnames(df2)<-c("Group.1","x")
freq<-rbind(df2,freq)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `table` and it's `useNA` argument. Much more efficient than `aggregate` and saves lots of typing too

```
as.data.frame(table(df$CarType, useNA = "ifany"))
##        Var1 Freq
## 1      AUDI    2
## 2       BMW    2
## 3 CHEVROLET    1
## 4      <NA>    2
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way

Answer (score 0):

By default, factors don't consider NA a level, due to the default argument of exclude = NA. Switching it to exclude = NULL will give you what you need:

```
freq<-aggregate(factor(df$CarType, exclude = NULL),by=list(factor(df$CarType, exclude = NULL)),function(c) length(c))
```

Comment: Or use `addNA` to save some typing.